# Can i do 'DESCRIBE KEYSPACES' from cqlengine?

Tags: cassandra, cqlengine

I'm using cqlengine from Django. Is there a way to make `DESCRIBE KEYSPACES` from it. It works form `cqlsh`.
Couldn't find anything in [Docs](https://cqlengine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet is getting it from the cluster metadata. `DESCRIBE` is not part of `cql` but cqlsh is using the python driver just like `cqlengine` so you can use same mechanism:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/16490a48b02b6f206a78717e9b816983f0b76bb1/bin/cqlsh.py#L619

```
map(str, yourconnection.metadata.keyspaces.keys())
```

from the metadata you can collect most data you want like this. You can also query the system schema tables but that changes between versions a bit so I would recommend letting driver do it for you.